# unable to keep normal case for text swift ui , getting converted to uppercase forcefully

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some text field which is getting converted to all caps forcefully.

I have tried playing around with these two fields but I am either able to convert it all to lowercase or all uppercase not the inherited value

fields I have played around with:
textCase (iOS 14 only) and autocapitalization.
I have tried using different fonts as well.

How the text looks like : Either CLOSE (when I dont set any property) or close when I set it to lowercase but I want it as Close.

```
Text("Close")
.font(.system(size: 15))
//.font(.custom("Maison Neue", size: 15))
.textCase(.lowercase)
.autocapitalization(.words)
```

Any idea on why the case is getting converted to uppercase automatically?

Comment: Same here and I cannot find why

Comment: Did any of you manager to figure out what caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why but when I created new struct for the text and added the struct in the main view, the fonts worked fine.

dont know why it was getting overridden before. kind of like this.

if someone knows why this can happen, please lmk.

```
struct SingleCellHeaderView: View {
    
    var text: String!
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text).foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(height: 20, alignment: .leading)
            .font(.custom("Maison Neue", size: 13))
            .padding(.init(top: 12, leading: 20, bottom: 12, trailing: 12))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out why this happens? I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Xcode feature. You have turned on "Show non-localized strings" in your scheme options.

***When you run your app, the nonlocalized strings appear in all caps.***
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-interface-for-localization

[image: Scheme options]